# IIS. How to Replace Contents of IIS Sites Without Stopping The Web Server

Tags: iis

In order to update our IIS Site we delete then replace contents of the associated physical path. However, sometimes we are not able to dele some files and/or folders as they are "being in use".
[image]

How should we proceed in such cases?

Comment: What you asked is equivalent to how to achieve blue/green deployments on a single IIS machine, so you might find articles like https://octopus.com/docs/deployments/patterns/blue-green-deployments/blue-green-deployments-in-iis helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the application you used.

If you use asp.net application, you can replace the content of sites directly. When asp.net application was deployed on IIS at beginning, IIS will load it firstly and create a shadow copy in temp file. All requests will be handled by the shadow copy. When you update the files, it creates a new AppDomain to service any new requests, and signals the previous AppDomain to shut down as soon as it has finished servicing any current requests.

If you use asp.net core application, you need to stop application, then update it. Asp.net core application is different from asp.net application. It actually runs in kestrel. IIS just acts as a proxy to forward requests to kestrel.